# Removing a substring of a value in a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a Dataframe with a column as such

| Product_ID |
| --- |
| 1234 |
| 1234-AA |
| 1234-BB |
| 1234 |

And I want to remove the -AA -BB suffixes from the values

| Product_ID |
| --- |
| 1234 |
| 1234 |
| 1234 |
| 1234 |

I've tried using `str.replace` and `str.contains`, but they don't seem to work

Comment: have you tried using Series.str.extract('\d\d\d\d")?

Comment: What about splitting on `'-'` and keeping the fist part? `df['Product_ID']..str.split('-').str[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about:

```
df['Product_ID_refined'] = df['Product_ID'].str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use regex then convert it back into a DataFrame. Below is some code that worked for me.

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None)
removeStrings = r'|'.join(-AA,-BB)
text = re.sub(removeStrings, '', str(data))
```